# Is it possible to create both FTP and GitHub deployment on one website in Microsoft Azure

Tags: ftp, github

I have a website hosted on Windows Azure and it is initially linked to GitHub deployment. My question is, is it still possible to create an FTP deployment even if I have my site linked to GitHub already? I just want to access my site through FTP. Is this possible? If yes, how can I create one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is [possible](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-manage/).

> **Download the publish profile -** Click this link to download your publish profile for your website. The publish profile contains your
>   credentials (user name and password) and the URLs for uploading
>   content to your website with FTP and Git. The profile file is in XML
>   format and can be viewed in a text editor.
>
> **Set up deployment credentials -** Click to create a user name and password for uploading content to your website with FTP or Git. You
>   can use these credentials to push content to any website in your
>   subscription. (See FTP Credentials.) Note: Authentication to an FTP
>   host or Git repository by using Microsoft Account (Live ID)
>   credentials is not supported.

**FTP Credentials**

> FTP Credentials There are two sets of FTP credentials that you can
>   use, deployment credentials and publishing profile credentials. Here
>   are the main differences:
>
> Deployment credentials
>
> Associated with a Microsoft account. Can be used to deploy to any web
>   site, in all subscriptions associated with the account. You pick the
>   username/password Typically used for git or FTP deployment Publishing
>   profile credentials
>
> Associated with a single website. You don’t pick the username or
>   password. Typically used for Web Deploy, but can also be used for FTP.
>   You can use either set of credentials. The FTP and FTPS host names are
>   listed on the dashboard, under Quick glance.